# Restrict Typescript decorator to void or Promise<void> functions

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to create a decorator which can only be applied to methods of `void` or `Promise<void>`.

```
class TestClass {
  // correctly compiles
  @Example()
  test() {}

  // should compile, but doesn't
  @Example()
  async testPromise() {}

  // correctly fails to compile
  @Example()
  async testBad() {
    return 'test';
  }

  // correctly fails to compile
  @Example()
  async testBadPromise() {
    return 'test';
  }
}
```

In general I'm familiar with the strategy for refining decorated types, but I can't figure out a union type to allow for the promises. The following minimal example works for the `void` method, but not for the `Promise<void>`:

```
type VoidFn = ((...args: any[]) => void) | ((...args: any[]) => Promise<void>);

const Example = () => (
  target: any,
  propertyKey: string | symbol,
  descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<VoidFn>,
) => {
  const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
  descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
    const result = originalMethod!.apply(this, args);
    return result;
  };
  return descriptor;
};
```

Bonus points if I can capture methods that potentially allow `undefined`, e.g `Promise<string | undefined>`. My particular use case is to capture, log, and swallow errors, which by nature requires the method to be able to "return nothing". Ultimately want something like:

```
const ErrorCapture = () => (
  target: any,
  propertyKey: string | symbol,
  descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<VoidFn>,
) => {
  const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
  if (originalMethod) {
    descriptor.value = function(this: any, ...args: any[]) {
      const handleError = (error: any) => {
        console.error(error);
        // etc.
      };
      try {
        const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        if (result instanceof Promise) {
          return result.catch(handleError);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        handleError(error);
      }
    };
    return descriptor;
  }
};
```

Comment: What is `Fn<T>` in your first example of a decorator?

Comment: Oops, that was a copy/paste error. For brevity, I originally had it as `type Fn<T> = (...args: any[]) => T;` 
`type VoidFn = Fn<void> | Fn<Promise<void>>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to thank @blaumeise20 for setting me on the right path. I did finally work out the types with the newer overload syntax that also allows it to be used on functions that *potentially* return `null`, either sync or async:

```
type Fn<T> = (...args: any[]) => T;

type CaptureType = {
  <T>(
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<Fn<T | null>>,
  ): TypedPropertyDescriptor<Fn<T | null>>;
  <T>(
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<Fn<Promise<T> | Promise<null>>>,
  ): TypedPropertyDescriptor<Fn<Promise<T> | Promise<null>>>;
  (
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<Fn<Promise<void>>>,
  ): TypedPropertyDescriptor<Fn<Promise<void>>>;
};

/**
 * Reports any errors that occur during execution of the function
 * and swallow the error. As there is no return value when an
 * error is swallowed, this is only valid for methods are of type `void`
 * or that can return either `null` or `Promise<null>`.
 */
function CaptureErrors(): CaptureType {
  return (
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: any[]) => any>,
  ) => {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    if (originalMethod) {
      descriptor.value = function (this: any, ...args: any[]) {
        const onError = (error: any) => {
          console.error(error);
          return null;
        };

        try {
          const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
          if (result && typeof result.then === 'function') {
            return result.then(undefined, onError);
          } else {
            return result;
          }
        } catch (error) {
          return onError(error);
        }
      };
    }

    return descriptor;
  };
}
```

```
class TestClass {
  @CaptureErrors()
  voidTest() {
    causeError();
  }

  @CaptureErrors()
  async asyncVoidTest() {
    causeError();
  }

  @CaptureErrors()
  nullableTest(): string | null {
    causeError();
    return 'foo';
  }

  @CaptureErrors()
  async asyncNullableTest(): Promise<string | null> {
    causeError();
    return 'foo';
  }

  // @ts-expect-error won't compile because not nullable
  @CaptureErrors()
  nonNullableTest() {
    return 'foo';
  }

  // @ts-expect-error won't compile because not nullable
  @CaptureErrors()
  async asyncNonNullableTest() {
    return 'foo';
  }
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8BQ1oAEUwlgALACgEpdoA3AewEsATBZKrGvYMAVwngBRAE7D6wqgG4aAX2w1CxMlRqQAngDtg0dVoBqTVoiQccebnwEixEytLxyFREhWp4NvEOABGIeGxNKAC5oZGFGDQBzaAAfaA8vTnNoHn4hUXEpLmhheCReYQ1oAHIAM3p6YvtoRzxFFxU8XW1mgDlPHz8AqhCABTEAW0YBAB4wiOi4hJAAPiTzVKsM22q8XPzCkvLK6troAHp9giQIAFp4AA8AB3hgJHPl6AB3eg1ipBT6AavGP2hvW6WeDxegfaZgXzwJxKVw0DSvdpeCFdYymbLrApFMoVKqyeR4Q7HM6XG53B42Z6vd6fb6-YEAxbA%20FgjrIqF1ZzKNw6CCaFq8rStBGsyHdYLQfpfYbwMZIcJROZmcwYzbYnZ4xxINQ3aAAMQ0I1gcwAvNByAA6S1gYSRCAhMAaNQAbQAupRoMa5rBpFqdUQrht-NrgaalYaZuRskhrZE8vbHQAabJXMQ3YRagDS8DUIXGUVioTUA289BASeSzEQwHCAfEIVgweYkrTWoAIlWa0hxCN9YaC9MZjNy9BxQ2bk3U-B02p2xBq4xa8IewbYP2OoPquHI8loza4zpE8nJ9OsznQnKJgXecXS8O8JW55263BG82p22Owuu0ve5KhqMjQLP9pRGAdB2HUdX2PD9Hy-btf0GEDALiYDRjAmZqm3cxd1jJB4zUO9oBTegWzUU9cwvfM4mvEsy2yB950XesoJI98Z0-RdlxGVCZQYFhByHGhIPHN9p1nRjvy4niRj45gBOkGRpGwfYACoVNwFToAAJXgK5xBOA81GgKcbBgJBSGIaB6GAYACmgZgCkvS5bl4JBGFeKzSmgczgVKXgtDc14NIPZhQieMAvHoJ5vNIYETPEc1oAAQTM2LcmgYYQRyPJMToCLeGBJ5YqKB1gvi4QMpgCBwsip54GYBMYsyzLXhAIzaAilhoHKCqBjyUh6GYGBrWBegvN9YEAANZMm4LxBiyyeCKFUingRgfIqybpkmqzNukgdJvNDT9mwPyAvcopOVcEJ-UDMdgSVFazSjGN9wdAij1Yk9swo%20VJkLG86IrDjv2YkToPY2DOItK0bTtQzXXdT1DMEvAkcVbJgFeZBdsYSIIgigBZfrBo9eyQYSjqQAK1YMq88hxDxgmQGJ8zBvdJVgah79zSpgqybOu4LrNczhnwxrLXNGN4fexH5mSbhsY%20V5rHm01yHK-D0flhXFY0CBS3gc1yo15Y7GyXWnumWnkkU-Fde84QjM5h2sf1j5cggTwPlNRn8Y0ImSeYKWriuNryFFiBGul82HfMRh6c973oAAMhT7zgzG7KvZAJBzR8opjSLrZ-KFqkOYth2nqT3P8%20K8h-MrUoInqxqVbNm2FZkYyQAEHW4%20rxBvc723K4cFIYTNcqK7jtYcs2dubFNmxY4duRdbt0f0XnooGKfYRdgU%20RBcCopGVV2x5nMsRoo0eBovui-yGKehSBBABCYpzbt7A3Zx2gpwJyMqaZoZptZKj-h8CIyAHTABDPEe%20cBjBoEgBALIesDZ%20CllAd85BoHRi0EbWSYoPTF2mKvP%20htsECHTOQcgYBwrrQyu7WBRtmgGBYGKJGZCOgUOxlQ1BuD8GsPNOCUUqJuGmnIdUShWDBG0PoYwqBLDCHYL5IiTo-gJGSPiLwmR-CsEgHoJEZ%20EUQApFisAAA1jAK4gjmCf2oD-AB4RShqCkEAA)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make your example work as intended. The secret here is to use *function overloads* which adds more signatures to a function. This is the final code:

```
const Example = () => {
  function dec(
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: any[]) => Promise<void>>,
  ): TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: any[]) => Promise<void>>;
  function dec(
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: any[]) => void>,
  ): TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: any[]) => void>;
  function dec(
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: any[]) => any>,
  ) {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
      const result = originalMethod!.apply(this, args);
      return result;
    };
    return descriptor;
  }
  return dec;
};

class TestClass {
  // correctly compiles
  @Example()
  test() {}

  // does compile
  @Example()
  async testPromise() {}

  // correctly fails to compile
  @Example()
  testBad() {
    return 'test';
  }

  // correctly fails to compile
  @Example()
  async testBadPromise() {
    return 'test';
  }
}
```

I also made a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAogDwIYFsAOAbApjAvDACgEo8A+GAbwCgYYAzAVzGCgEtwYATLYAm2mFCQAnAOZYoALhhIwATwA0-WmmEg0WYVDkBpLHOnRhrMKJgAfGBDkoARiAxKBXLBGDG0UEMOkAVORqcAApqGlpyACKu7qye3gA8BAB0KSKiENKycgDaALokuOQhICisEFjxAG4grJykpE4wRH4BWMGhmtpRbh5ewokpSWkZMvJ5BUVqpeVVNXWkANz8jMxsHNy8yoJpEpnyjSod4XoGVlDGphZWNvaOW9w9sX0tgcVhXdG9CcmpYiNZ4zIMGqtQa-GaMH8ryOH0ecX6PyGfz2OXyQJBdSWtBWLHYYBcm2cQjEu1Gii2qnUnV0+kM5xMZks1jsDgOLjhz0hrXaVPC3Ri8IGv3SKMBhTJYNoJGozlAkFg3lYohMSAwAFkJAALECcPDsgV9JKVVUMLBYgQPA3eI0mnD4HFrfGI4aitEy5wwOXQGDCVwMDCwfCK5VgVUaqDazgAQiGaEwcgIEbKChkfyI5ucvqgDGE+N9EH9UAzMAAvsWszn8ZavsJzSX+BXcwSlmWqFRgBgkBAIJDXFAAMKd7uUfgAelHnu8vpYGDkk-QrGwEH4AAFEKhMFhiPwoH3iJR62OJ5wQK552hF1hV+v0Nht7Qu3JmII+8VplvpYfaOPJ8Jp1BZ3oJBFx7Lxz0va9kFvD8dz7AAhJBOH3d1aEbfEAHJd2gdC6zbb8J1AP8eAAuc6GAjBQJAcDsEgjc7yIfhH2fLCoAQnl32QrY0JgTC+xw-h63rIA).

It works as follows: The `Example` function returns another function with multiple overloads for each possible method it can be used on. But don't get confused with the third signature, it is the implementation signature.

Comment: Wow. I'm familiar with overloading, but I had no idea I could use it with inner functions like this. I had made attempts to overload `Example` itself, but didn't get it to work correctly. I guess this is doing it implicitly, though. Thanks! I was really frustrated with this one.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your code, and found out interesting results.

Case 1: decorate on normal function [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8CwAoa0A9IdMAPYBOF8wSIAnqWQLYAOAliIngQAICiADzBsuACgCUPaEkRJJWAL55pA4aPiTps5AGUkFdgDsA5pIBc0AGpl2AEwBK8JAFcKR%20HaxESAHgC00AAWYABu8DJk0GB2Xjb2Tq7untAAZpRwupHQAO6UANbSBNRJRtAA5DpI5QDc0sq4DXhI9KwR8Y7Obh5eALzQobZeAD7QyIamdbgtbdZDAGJl-WIAdGtgFCYQlmBG9ADaALoS0L0AfHMJXcl2U3jkRsjQQiKsXKfQCuef2hsmzjs9gAaaSsChkNoUFoAaXg9Es42MJmgowg9GYACMyCAQfhoHZEMBDKwkJRLLBWp4AArgyEtAAihOJpIovg6izOuJO3xweIeT0o7BMxjAIAAss4gmQ%20vimewSZQVqFRS54FMCASIET5SylSqIv1Ui4jLR2GQyqt1ptttE9kcTryCAR%20UhoNQIC4QK7%20oLhUZRRKkFK7ABCFZgVhvehiIPsCBA6LWiTqp0lbpuxCepApxQptPuWVa5mUKa5oA)

```
class TestClass {
  // correctly compiles
  @Example()
  test() {}

  @Example()
  testString(): VoidReturned { // <- have to add VoidReturned for TS to work
    return 'test';
  }
}

type VoidReturned = void | string;
type VoidFn<T> = (...args: any[]) => T;

const Example = () => (
  target: any,
  propertyKey: string | symbol,
  descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<VoidFn<VoidReturned>>,
) => {
  const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
  descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
    const result = originalMethod!.apply(this, args);
    return result;
  };
  return descriptor;
};
```

TS knows that `testString()` is of type `() => string` because it return string `'test'`. While the descriptor expect a function of type `() => void | string`. Clearly, those types mismatch.
To fix that we have to add `: VoidReturned` so the type of `testString()` is `() => void | string`

Case 2: decorate on async function [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8CwAoa0A9IdAO4D2ATgNbQB25peBAAgKIAeYAtgA4jwAFAEpm0SAE86waEkRIACpXLcAlhCHCAXNCUr18ADwA1cqoAmAJXhIArpTrxzAPixiAvnjHEyVWgyZ8aHYuPgERMUlpWXkAITBzER09NQ0TMysbe0cXHCCCSiyHaAByOWQSgG4PLyCfChp6RjEQnn5NSIgpGXKkePMUgyTdZVSjUwtrOwcnVzyCAqK6Ut6qmtxPXDwkCV54aAnM6ZzoAF5oADcM6AAfaGRKVToAc2rcHb2DjIAxZfPBAB0QLAlGeEB0YDoEgA2gBdYRnVyHKbZJxvD77QYaQ6-M7QQHA0Hg8RQuEI06uLHjDIomYuN54ABmtmkSFU5GWnDa4QR8wWhWO0GZrPZdEESBBzxsEKhABpoLxlHtKDsANLwCQ6B5PZ63e4SbgAI3IIHl5kQwEevCQVB0sF2Tj0yp2ABELVabZRDFScXRnLyxAsFsAOchoFRVM8nmAQABZGwAC3I5jxEtBNmhivIzok6oksIZ%20SD0HNEEtqmtVABFxjtn253EXWiwuAbI5%20KBAMlxMhMPhbiLxeDoaQ0EKEFsIFH5zApDAqlHggjUboMfjSCT5gAhMIu7x%20BJxZKbPLu8I3kOhwLsmPEJPR5AvpMlmjA8X3IXL7fBaXy5XKBeCybB%20QA)

```
class TestClass {
  // work now
  @Example()
  async testPromise(): Promise<VoidReturned> {
  }

  // work now
  @Example()
  async testBad(): Promise<VoidReturned>{
    return 'test';
  }

  // work now
  @Example()
  async testBadPromise(): Promise<VoidReturned> {
    return 'test';
  }
}

type VoidReturned = void | string;
type VoidFn = (...args: any[]) => VoidReturned;
type PromiseVoidFn = (...args: any[]) => Promise<VoidReturned>;

function Example() {
    return function(target: any, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<PromiseVoidFn>) {
        const originalMethod = target[propertyKey];

        descriptor.value =  async function (...args: any[]) {
            const result = await (originalMethod!).apply(target, args);
            return result as VoidReturned;
        };

        return descriptor;
    }
};
```

Similar to Case 1, we have to add `: Promise<VoidReturned>` so the types match.
So if they are used separately it works.

Case 3: decorate on normal and async function [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8CwAoa0A9IdMAPYBOF8wSIAnqWQLYAOAliIngQAICiADzBsuACgCUPaEkRJJWAL55pxGXOgAzStGQV2AOwDm0gcNHxJ02cgDKSfcckAuaADUy7ACYAleEgBXCgN4L2gAH2gABQoWdgh4AB4Pbz9A4NCAPixpAgJqdINoAHI9QyNigG5pZVxVEgMyJGgAd0oAa3LTIRFWcSl8aEh6A2B1ZBi4hJd3T19-IJCwyMnmeKSU%20cKszCISRIBaA6GIEbHNANGkdjIi5gDkaAALMAA3eGgCxZl6Vg-V9aJWDZW4MGoqQZqJBPeKtDrlAA00EaFGYYBAWkutBuBm65j6lgGBBsSAAQmAvDNNmlFqEItFYmsEsk5jSMl5MjhBvkFsESiTiuC6pCGk04RROsY8b1%20tJhqNxmSKQDphJXNTeUt6SqNqzNVksHtoIdjvLzljrrdoPdHi93p9NT8-gypklgdBQfRcg7Cvy5FUhbU8Ehfh8NdswgBeaCvOb0srGaq4EPOzYAMSK0bEADpc2AKEYIK4wAZ6ABtAC6Emgkey4dpXkqRpRaIxFyuOODoZdTPg6cz0BzeYLRaGpcr1drPcB9fZmSbajNmI7ty7zoAsuxBKEMzXB7ns-nC8Xx1Wa3W9RHtYyZ5eG-OjWtt2ElyWwi30RD29irT0LAouTyH1vm-S0DDEJAj38E96CRVhYj%20CgQwAaXgehXATIx43oZgACMyBAJEvEQYB9FYJBKFcWBQy8SZEJDAAREiyIoihEk3Z8M0yatAKAvJyAMR5KHYIxDHRdd-CeMgoxkKCkDLeCyHo%20hUPoCsk29IDiIgUj2HIyhs1edEAg%20aMTjOZcfyKIdDxHGCJxybk%20KAgTHmoCAAhAZpozAFowHYZoxGE0SDHEyTpIAQgkQ9WD6egILkpEjwgCQk2c5yvj5dzPOaSBZlSfVG00vJFA0pygMyoptN0-SKDSkq8FKoA):
Notice that normal and async function differ only on returned type, we create new type called MixedFn to represent both normal and async function. And make sure to add return type for each method to match the returned type of MixedFn

```
class TestClass {
  // correctly compiles
  @Example()
  test() {}

  // test for string
  @Example()
  testString(): VoidReturned | Promise<VoidReturned> {
      return 'string';
  }

  // not working
  @Example()
  async testPromise(): VoidReturned | Promise<VoidReturned>{ // <-- error here: async function must have return type Promise<T> only
  }

  // this working, normal function
  @Example()
  testBad(): VoidReturned | Promise<VoidReturned> {
    return 'test'
  }

  // not working
  @Example()
  async testBadPromise(): VoidReturned | Promise<VoidReturned> { // <-- error: async function must have return type Promise<T> only
    return 'test';
  }
}

type VoidReturned = void | string;
type VoidFn = (...args: any[]) => VoidReturned; // normal function
type PromiseVoidFn = (...args: any[]) => Promise<VoidReturned>; // async function
type MixedFn = (...args: any[]) => VoidReturned | Promise<VoidReturned>; // mixed async and normal

function Example() {
    return function(target: any, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<MixedFn>) {
        const originalMethod = target[propertyKey];

        descriptor.value =  async function (...args: any[]) {
            const result = await (originalMethod!).apply(target, args);
            return result as VoidReturned;
        };

        return descriptor;
    }
};
```

Only 1 issue left is async function (by JS spec) must only have returned type `Promise<T>` while our async method have type `VoidReturned | Promise<VoidReturned>`, we can fix that to convert async function to normal function but **return an Promise** instead:

```
class TestClass {
  // correctly compiles
  @Example()
  test() {}

  // test for string
  @Example()
  testString(): VoidReturned | Promise<VoidReturned> {
      return 'string';
  }

  // work
  @Example()
  testPromise(): VoidReturned | Promise<VoidReturned> {
  }

  // work now
  @Example()
  testBad(): VoidReturned | Promise<VoidReturned>{
    return (async function() {
      // your async code here
      return 'test';
    })();
  }

  // work now
  @Example()
  testBadPromise(): VoidReturned | Promise<VoidReturned> {
    return Promise.resolve('test'); // async like above is preferred
  }
}

type VoidReturned = void | string;
type VoidFn = (...args: any[]) => VoidReturned; // normal function
type PromiseVoidFn = (...args: any[]) => Promise<VoidReturned>; // async function
type MixedFn = (...args: any[]) => VoidReturned | Promise<VoidReturned>; // mixed async and normal

function Example() {
    return function(target: any, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<MixedFn>) {
        const originalMethod = target[propertyKey];

        descriptor.value =  async function (...args: any[]) {
          try {
            const result = await (originalMethod!).apply(target, args);

            if (result === undefined || result === null) {
              // do something with result void
              // 
            }

            return result;
          } catch (error) {
            // handle error
          }
           
           return;
        };

        return descriptor;
    }
};
```

[Final code here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8CwAoa0A9IdMAPYBOF8wSIAnqWQLYAOAliIngQAICiADzBsuACgCUPaEkRJJWAL55pxGXOgAzStGQV2AOwDm0gcNHxJ02cgDKSfcckAuaADUy7ACYAleEgBXCgN4L2gAH2gABQoWdgh4AB4Pbz9A4NCAPixpAgJqdINoAHI9QyNigG5pZVxVEgB3SgBrUyERVnEpfHVkGLiEl3dPX38gkLDI-uZ4pJTRwqycntr66CaKZugDMga2807LboIbJAAhMC8h%20bTx0Ijo2JmE5JHbjK9MnB78seDoMSQegGYBaAIgpDsMgGBTfPJ5NT0MhBaBAkFMLzwaAAC3g1FyeQK4xKpyqBMUEkk1RWKh6ag2Wx2ex6Zg6XWscguXmms2ubz%20EwePJeNwFSzhhIFjwG8AAdNQIGQQAA3SzFUkSSpEEho0EgdjNLFgABGZFV0Hi0FY1E0mjxoRqeFWuCQ9FYWNFizCAF5oMqRg8ysZqa73cNvAAxIq%20sSyuNgChGCCuMAGegAbQAuhJoN7sp67l4tWodhRmGAQGCIVCDHhQ1jhfB5lHcwC47KE0mU2mszm89LnnN%20V7MsWdRBgaDNODaDW626sQBZdiCUItmPtzvJ1E97O5-PDwtCp6zV6pMWfMfQGarsK6ndhUvlkC06fV6HQdoWWEEon-N%20ztCYhIJ2-jdvQAA0VqxO6FCugA0vA9CuEGRiBvQzCmiAUGYhAwD6KwSCUK4sALtyMF4q6AAiiD4ewhGUIky63lGmQ5hK8IEOQBjINAlDsEYhgVou-jYmQPoyKBSDptaZCwQhSGZtSBLwrhdEMRQsrKhWARYr6qITuiAGQh%20sbxom26phme4cZxJwUIwtl2Vx0K8QqAQgEgrZgA0YDsF5Yj8YJBjCaJ4kAIQSB2rCdPQwFSVBW6arSzmcewmgAu5nm5t6vrgpimiGPc4SRFlXm5b6BgeSA7Eqal2rQF4ZC6CwonlOs-nYtAZV%20iMdWpWo-Wcc69WSoU3WIB5SDUqNiikGASDAF1Yh4rEFC1T89VqNiqZeFw0CrZQQ0ELUo3QMdvyFDNzmKMpm3wn%20RRqQRREUNdJ1OpUQA), I also change the implementation of `Example` to point `target` as `this` for original method

Comment: I really appreciate the response, but several issues:
a) I can't force all of those changes onto methods just to allow adding the decorator. I would need `TestClass` to remain as above.
b) That silently converts synchronous methods to return a promise, because `descriptor.value` is being **replaced** by an async function.
c) `string` was just the type of a particular example; decorated methods could return any arbitrary type as long as `undefined` is an option.
Also, in a `MethodDecorator`, `target` refers to the prototype of the class containing the decorated method, not the instance.